# discord.py sort roles from highest

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord.py

```
@commands.command(aliases=['ui'])
    async def userinfo(self, ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
        if member == None:
            member = ctx.message.author
        else:
            member = member
    
        roles = [role for role in sorted(member.roles, key=lambda role: ctx.guild.roles)]

        embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.colour.purple(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=f"User Info - {member}")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id)
        embed.add_field(name="Guild name:", value=member.display_name)
        embed.add_field(name="Created at:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p"))
        embed.add_field(name="Joined at:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p"))
        embed.add_field(name=f"Roles ({len(roles)})", value=" ".join([role.mention for role in roles][1:]))
        embed.add_field(name="Top role:", value=member.top_role.mention)
        embed.add_field(name="Bot?", value=member.bot)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

it doesnt give me any errors but it doesnt work as i wanted it to. I want it to sort the roles according to the server's role hierarchy. All I should have to change for it to work is `roles` but I can't think of what

Comment: Please check [`Role.position`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=role.#discord.Role.position)

Answer (score 1):

The roles should already be sorted by their position in the role hierarchy. Nonetheless you can use the `role.position` attribute

```py
roles = list(sorted(member.roles, key=lambda role: role.position))
```

Comment: To add to that, functional operators like `sorted`, `map`, `filter`, etc. return a generator. Once you iterated to the end of the list, you will always get an empty result afterwards. So convert the generator to a list to exhaust the generator right away and store it in a list, as shown in the answer.